# Django 2 language site once again

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I've already created my simple blog in Python Django.
For now, I am interested how to maintain two languages on my blog.
I know about Django internationalization but I do not want to translate button text in my templates.
I've created post model with several fields for different languages: description_ru, description_en. At the end of the day, I want to show fields based on user language preference.

What best practices now (in 2017) to that. Many projects seem to be out of date now;-(

Maybe I should create separate apps for different languages?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdbpinOmMeo ("Data internationalization in Django" by Raphael Michel, DjangoCon Europe 2017) and pick your i18n 3rd party app. In my projects, I choose [`django-modeltranslation`](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) app.

Comment: You could look into django-cms. Supporting multiple languages in articles is fairly straight forward and it's not that difficult to adapt existing apps.

Comment: Django-cms is cool and I try already use it.But at the end of the day it seems for me to simpler to build project from scratch than to learn another cms. Maybe in future I will adopt it.

Comment: And thanks for video, Django-modeltranslation looks promising - I'll try to test it.